# OLEDB Connection won't connect to Access 2013 database

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am trying to use the OLEDB connection to load my database to my Visual Basic program. However, I am receiving this error:"Could not find installable ISAM."

I am using Microsoft Access Database 2013. As far as I'm aware, 12.0 is the correct version.

This is my code:

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim databaseprovider As String
    Dim dblocation As String
    databaseprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dblocation = "Date source = C:\HotelBookingDatabase.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = databaseprovider & dblocation
    con.Open()
    MsgBox("open")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("closed")
```

Edit - I have changed "Data source..." to "Data Source..." and installed 2007 Office System drivers, but that hasn't helped my cause.

Edit #2 - Looked at the code above again today. I figured out the problem. Instead of "Data Source", my code has "DATE Source". Oops. Updated code, which works:

```
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dbprovider As String
        Dim dbsource As String
        dbprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbsource = "Data Source = C:\HotelBookingDatabase.accdb;"
        con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
        con.Open()
        MsgBox("ok")
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("bye")
```

Comment: You have "date source", is that correct or just a typo. Have you seen this? http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/resolving-could-not-find-installable-isam-error

Comment: If you start by using the [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will avoid typos like "Date Source" instead of "Data Source". Also, the root of C: is a particularly bad place to put a file.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you, I didn't notice that, but even when I changed it - it still gave me the same error. I suppose I'll have to download the software in the link you provided? Thanks Andrew, too.

Comment: I installed the 2007 Office System Driver but that didn't help either. Forgive my ignorance, but will my database still function if I on't have the con.open code etc.? It seems to run fine without the line, but obviously that's not good for me as I have no indication of whether the database is "open" or not.

Comment: Ought you to have a space between the end of the `dblocation` and the start of the `databaseprovider`?

Comment: @BrianHooper I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted out the problem.

I changed my code to this:

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\HotelBookingDatabase.accdb")

        con.Open()
        MsgBox("ok")
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("bye")
```